# How to make a 'double' correspond with an 'integer'

Tags: java, android, string, integer, double

I recently added a method in my application that will automatically format a textview from lets say: "50000" to "50,000" which works absolutely perfect. Now the problem I am running into is that in my application there are multiple button functions the add or remove certain amounts from that text view, so lets just say the textview = "5,000" and when you click the button it removes "1000"
The problem is that it force closes the app because the textview isn't technically an integer anymore, it's a string. Here's the Code and Error.

```
    //formats the textview to show commas
    double number = Double.parseDouble(textView1.getText().toString());
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
    textView1.setText(formatter.format(number));


    Button btnremove1000 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnremove1000);
    btnremove1000.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            int amount = Integer.parseInteger(textView1.getText()
                    .toString()) - 1000;
            textView1.setText(String.valueOf(amount));

            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,
                    "1,000 removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            msg.show();
        }
    });
```

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "5,000"
```

Now how can I do this so I can still display the commas yet add and remove values? 
 
The only thing i can think of is to somehow remove the comma, add/remove a value, then reformat it to display the comma again?

Comment: removing all the commas form the string should do it. unless you are adding some other text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
int amount = Integer.parseInteger(textView1.getText().toString()) - 1000;
```

with:

```
String fromTV = textView1.getText().toString();

String commaRemoved = fromTV.replace(",", "");

int amount = Integer.parseInteger(commaRemoved) - 1000;
```

In one line:

```
int amount = Integer.parseInteger(
                    textView1.getText().toString().replace(",", "")) - 1000;
```

Edit: Use `replace()` in place of `replaceAll()`, as suggested by Eng.Fouad.

Comment: Use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()`. The latter is used only with regular expression. The name of these two methods are misleading, they should have named them `replaceAll()` and `replaceRegex()`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad `The name of these two methods are misleading, they should have named them replaceAll() and replaceRegex()`. Makes sense. BTW, is using `","` as regex to match all commas wrong? This was what I was going for with `replaceAll(",", "")`.

Comment: @CoreyWilliams You're welcome. To be honest, I would have gone with EJP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DecimalFormat.parse()` method, using the same `DecimalFormatter` you used to format the string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you shouldn't store your data in a View.

Try and keep it as seperate as possible.

```
int amount = 5000000;

textView.setText(formatter.format(amount));

button.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        amount -= 1000;
        textView.setText(formatter.format(amount));
    }
});
```

Here the data is stored outside of the view and is easy to manage. Data only ever goes in one direction, into the views.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int amount = Integer.parseInteger(textView1.getText().toString()) - 1000;` this line with the following code :-

`String strText = textView1.getText().reaplace(",","");`
`int amount = Integer.parseInteger(strText) - 1000`

And 1 more thing you don't need to specify format like ###,###,###. It will be enough if you use ##,###.